# make two livedata values affect each other in android

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have two Livedata. One for USD and the other for EUR. I want to change a value for the other value to be changed and vice versa.
However, It seems impossible as long as they both observing and changing each others' value as making this process a infinite loop which causes to app crash.
Lets say I have Livedata A and Livedata B.
If I change value of A then, the observer of A changes value of B, then observer of B changes value of A again and so on.
[This](https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv=574726742&q=1%20usd%20to%20eur&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjl7NrPxoGCAxXUs1YBHeMCAvcQBSgAegQIBhAB&biw=1920&bih=995&dpr=2) is exactly what I want. One value changes for the other, but do not go in infinite loop. I would like to achieve this with Livedata. Is there any suggestion for this? or any other different approach is also welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Observer pattern but added an extra condition where calculation executes only when the current view is on focus.

```
    viewModel.currentDollar.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { currentDollar ->
        if (currentDollar != null) {
            if (activity?.currentFocus == binding.tietDollarInputText) {
                viewModel.calculateDollarToEur(currentDollar)
            }
        }
    }
    viewModel.currentEur.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { currentEur ->
        if (currentEur != null) {
            if (activity?.currentFocus == binding.tietEurInputText) {
                viewModel.calculateEurToDollar(currentEur)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have two variables per each currency.

- LiveData USD and exchanged USD
- LiveData Euro and exchanged Euro

The exchanged USD observes LiveData Euro, while the exchanged Euro observes LiveData USD.

Both LiveData of USD and Euro are used for user's input. If user input a value onto EditText, it is taken as input to the corresponding LiveData (USD or Euro).

An exchanged value is displayed as hint text of EditText.

Thus, a LiveData and its observant can be one-way process.

Comment: If I understood correctly, it needs two input source and additional two more output source as using hint text of EditText. However, it isn't really what I want though. I hope something like what google currency convert does as I tagged the link in the post.

Answer (score 0):

try this approach

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val usdInput = MutableLiveData<Double>()
    private val eurInput = MutableLiveData<Double>()
    private val rate: Double

    val usdOutput = MediatorLiveData<Double>().apply {
        addSource(usdInput) {
            value = it
        }
        addSource(eurInput) {
            value = it * rate
        }
    }

    val eurOutput = MediatorLiveData<Double>().apply {
        addSource(eurInput) {
            value = it
        }
        addSource(usdInput) {
            value = it / rate
        }
    }

    fun onUsdInput(input:Double) {
        usdInput.value = input
    }

    fun onEurInput(input:Double) {
        eurInput.value = input
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be a good approach based on extra explanation. I tried it with TextChangeListener, Observer pattern, Two-way data binding but none worked with it.